# Custom Error Page redirecting to local URL

Tags: sharepoint-server, publishing-site, custom-masterpage, variations, dns

I have a Web Applcation which contains a Publishing Site with Variations feature enabled. The following is and example URL for the site `http://test-server.com/en`

However when I type a wrong URL, an error occurs it takes me to Page Not Found error page but the URL changes to the following:

```
http://windows-pc:29420/pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx?requestUrl=http://localhost:29420/en/whatsfa"
```

I want the URL to point to the following domain name URL:

```
http://test-server.com/en
```

and not to local URL like:

```
http://windows-pc:29420/pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is PowerShell to set your page not found URL:

```
$spsite = Get-SPSite "Web site URL"
$spsite.filenotfoundurl
$spsite.filenotfoundurl = "/sites/yoursite/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx"
```

Besides, customizing the 404 Redirection in SharePoint for your reference:

https://www.chakkaradeep.com/2009/06/23/customizing-the-404-redirection-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks for that answer.
However I have a Variations site with English and Arabic versions to it. Now I want to have two different Error pages one for Arabic and one for English. How can I achieve that?